# Calculating heatloss caused by vent?

Tags: thermodynamics

We've got a property where we have done the heatloss calcs, to size the new radiators.

In most cases we are 20% over the target BTU output, so we have a bit of margin.

The project has been instructed to install vents in some rooms for gas burning fires and cookers. (UK building regs)

How much heatloss would a 100x100mm constantly open to atmosphere vent cause ?

Based upon a) an external temp of 10C, internal 20C. b) an external temp of 2C, internal of 20C.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main types of heat loss: Radiation, Convection and Conduction.

Conduction is directly proportional to change in temperature

Radiation is proportional to 4th power of temperature. For situation 1, 0.54W is lost per second (not significant) and situation 2, 0.94W, also negligible

Convection is a little more complex, its best explained as movement of air due to varied density arising from different temperatures but for situations like a room it's quite significant. If the vent is vertically oriented (on the ceiling), convective losses will be much more significant.

Also the wind speed through the vent matters: Is there a fan? This will increase heat loss, which can be calculated as Q=mcT, with m being mass of air evacuated, c being specific heat capacity and T being temperature

Vent location on the wall may not be significant, unless there is a significant temperature gradient in the room (floor heating?) or the room is really large (like a hall). Take into account the density difference for hot and cold air, in a large room with little air circulation, the air above may be warmer

If you want a qualitative answer, try simulating it through Comsol or any other physics simulator

Comment: Thanks Dayruis, re. vent location, would the height of the vent on the wall make a difference, eg if it was higher up the wall or lower down on the wall ?